# Ubuntu 22.04 -- Random pop-up Hotspot Login appearing on desktop PCs (no wifi)

Tags: networking, 22.04, security, hot-spot

Today, for the first time since, well, ever [*], I saw my PC at home showing this screen, to me absolutely mysterious, with a 404 reported by NGNIX on a Hotspot Login page.  The PC is a desktop, connected via gigabit ethernet (as in, wired) to the home LAN; the machine does not even have a wifi device (not configured, anyway — it is possible that the motherboard has a wifi device.

Ignored it (a bit puzzled and worried).

Arrive at my workstation at work, also Ubuntu 22.04 and also exclusively wired connectivity, and surprise, the exact same screen mysteriously showing.  This is a partial screenshot:

[image]

My two questions (or question with a follow-up sub-question):

- What is this and why did it happen "randomly", but such a big coincidence?
- Should I be worried that my machines were breached?  (I have the SSH key on my machine at home that allows me to directly log in to the work machine)

[*] I have been working exclusively on Ubuntu since Ubuntu 8.04, and upgraded my two main machines (home and work PCs) from 18.04 to 22.04 shortly before the support period expired.

Comment: I am starting to suspect an update or patch that ran. I have 2 machines of 2 different versions (18.04 and 22.04) that started with this today. One is a VM and the other a desktop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just ignore it, close it and everything will continue as normal.

I had a similar thing occur quite frequently with my two instances of Ubuntu 22.04 when using a 4G router for my internet connection (mainly during the night and only evident the next morning) when switching on the monitor (the PCs are permanently on but the screen off). I put it down to a temporary interruption in the internet signal triggering the window in Firefox (usually full screen) and there was never any evidence that my system had been in any way compromised. It didn't always occur, just infrequently without any evident cause.

In the past 3 months my internet was upgraded to fibre. With the increased stability the window has not appeared since which has assured me that there indeed was no cause for concern previously.